# image hover animate

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have the following jQuery script that makes an orange transparent hover effect cover the image when it's rolled over.  How do I make it so this script will animate in and out (with a fade?)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#gallery a').bind('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).parent('li').css({position:'relative'});
        var img = $(this).children('img');
        $('<div />').text(' ').css({
            'height': img.height(),
            'width': img.width(),
            'background-color': 'orange',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'opacity': 0.5
        }).bind('mouseout', function(){
            $(this).remove();
        }).insertAfter(this);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#gallery a').bind('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).parent('li').css({position:'relative'});
        var img = $(this).children('img');
        $('<div />').text(' ').css({
            'height': img.height(),
            'width': img.width(),
            'background-color': 'orange',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'opacity': 0.5
        }).bind('mouseout', function(){
            $(this).fadeOut(function(){ $(this).remove(); }); // <--- added fadeout()
        }).insertAfter(this).fadein(); //  <--- added fadeIn()
    });

});
```

Comment: cool, thanks! it seems to fadeout properly, but initially on rollover it doesn't fade in